# How do I run Android's .apk files on linux without the Android emulator?

Tags: android, apk

I have a requirement, where I need to install the .apk files directly on my host PC, without the Android emulator. I want to install it directly on my Linux machine (x86 arch). I have a few noob questions with regard to the same:

- How is an .apk file organized?

  - Is it just one big binary file?

    - In this case, if I am using a phone with an x86 atom processor, does this mean that there will be a separate Android market segment which hosts apps ported to the x86 arch?
  - Is it an archive consisting of executables? (something like .rpm or .deb).

    - If so, then what is the format of the archive?
    - If so, do they have different .apk files for different architectures (x86, ARM, etc.).
    - If not, then how is it orgranized?
- What are the requirements to run the .apk file directly on my Linux PC running on x86 arch?

I do not have a very good background of Android and the .apk files, hence these questions.

Thanks and regards,

Hrishikesh Murali

Answer (score 9):

You cannot install .apk files directly onto your PC. Even though Android uses the Linux kernel, the applications runs on a totally different platform. APK files are ZIP file formatted packages based on the JAR file format, with .apk file extensions. They hold all of that program's code (such as .dex files), resources, assets, certificates, and manifest file. 
They run only on the [Dalvik virtual machine.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine)

Install Android OS on your PC, if you really want to run them from a computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ARChon to run apk in ubuntu:

1. Install the ARChon Runtime. 
   http::github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk/blob/master/archon.md
2. Open and enable the flag: chrome://flags/#enable-nacl,then restart Google-Chrome. (Important!)
3. Install existing android apps in the [website](https://huodong.ustc.edu.cn/Crx) or convert your favourite android apps by "[Online APK-CRX Converter](https://huodong.ustc.edu.cn/Crx).
4. Drag and drop the Google-Chrome extensions into the chrome://extensions/ page in the browser and it will be installed in your browser. Enjor it!

Answer (score 1):

1. An apk file is not an executable, it's just an archive file contaning all the resources and class files that are to be used by the application.
2. The apk is set to be unpacked and run by the Dalvik vm.
3. The elements that are contained inside the apk file are specifically designed and designated to be used in Android mobile phones and not a desktop PC running Linux. Though Android uses the Linux kernel, you definitely cannot run the apk file on a Linux machine, as you would an rpm or a deb file.

Comment: Thank you. Is it absolutely necessary that we need the 'dalvik vm' to run it, or can we replicate the operations by 'dalvik vm' manually, with tweaks, to make it run on linux directly?

Comment: No we cannot ! It will be like taking a human being who is designed to live and breath on earth , to Mars and tweaking Mars so as to accomodate human beings.

Comment: @Achilles Off topic, but random joke... There is two know mars missions planned, one by NASA and the other by MarsOne. These will later include teramorphing mars as there is not only ice on mars, but flowing water too. All one needs to synthesize an atmosphere is oxygen and electricity to create ozone. Back to topic, yes to "emulate" or reconstruct and optimise a vm is possible. But the time needed to do so is greater than the feasible use thereof (HrishikeshMurali)